# terraform chef provisioning - cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: chef, terraform, security, ssl

While configuring the chef provisioner I am running into the following error after running 'terraform apply'

```
chef_environment.terraform_01: Post https://10.90.239.223/organizations/mykitchen/environments: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

I tried this

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout chef.key -out chef.pem -nodes -days 365 -config req.conf

sudo chown opscode:opscode chef.*
sudo mv chef.* /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/.

sudo chef-server-ctl stop
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-server-ctl start
```

my req.conf

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=mystate
L=mycity
O=DevOps
OU=myname
emailAddress=myemail@mycompany.com
CN = 10.90.239.223

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP = 10.90.239.223
DNS.1 = 10.0.90.45
DNS.2 = 10.90.50.8
email = DevOps-3@10.90.239.223
URI = https://10.90.239.223/
```

but I am still getting

```
chef_environment.terraform_01: Post https://10.90.239.223/organizations/mykitchen/environments: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.90.239.223 because it doesn't contain any                                       IP SANs
```

In my chef provisioner config I also have

```
ssl_verify_mode = ":verify_none"
```

So far I am stumped.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered on Slack, the likely first issue here is that the output from `openssl req` is not a cert, it's a CSR. But there are some other lingering issues here too. It is recommended to use something like Certstrap to do internal cert generation rather than raw `openssl` commands as the modern standards are quite fiddly.

Comment: There's also [`cfssl`](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl), which appears to have more community adoption.